# Bootstrap 4 - Add text and button over video

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, html5-video, bootstrap-4

I am trying to get something like this.  But it must use Bootstrap 4.
   [image]

My current code looks like this:

```
<section class="banner embed-responsive-item">
    <video class="hidden-sm-down" autoplay="" loop="">
        <source src="http://www.example/home.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="http://www.example/home.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div class="float-left">YOUR EXPERIENCE STARTS</div><br>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Enquire Now</a>
</section>
```

Sadly the output just puts the text and button at the end of the image instead of on top of it.

Comment: Did you try absolute positioning? I would think there'd be plenty of examples already out there. It's not really specific to Bootstrap 4.

Comment: can you please share the css!

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/exghLtcy/

```css
video{
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  width:100%; 
}
.float-right{
  position:absolute;
}
h2{
  top:80px;
  right:0;
}
a{
  top:150px;
  right:50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="banner embed-responsive-item">
    <video class="hidden-sm-down" autoplay="" loop="">
        <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <h2 class="float-right">YOUR EXPERIENCE STARTS</h2><br>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg float-right" href="#" role="button">Enquire Now</a>
</section>
```

making your video relative in position and your content absolute, you can achieve what you have in image!

Hope it helps!

Html(Since the text in image is higher in font size, I've made it as h2 instead of div):

```
<section class="banner embed-responsive-item">
    <video class="hidden-sm-down" autoplay="" loop="">
        <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <h2 class="float-right">YOUR EXPERIENCE STARTS</h2><br>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg float-right" href="#" role="button">Enquire Now</a>
</section>
```

Css:(You got to change the position from top for your text and button)

```
video{
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  width:100%; 
}
.float-right{
  position:absolute;
}
h2{
  top:80px;
  right:0;
}
a{
  top:150px;
  right:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
video {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
}

a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 5%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the only way I got it to work, for now, was to place inline CSS. I placed my header outside of the section.

```
   <h3 style="font-size: 75px;
       font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
       color: #e8d5a0;
       position: absolute;
       top: 400px;
       left: 650px;
       display: inline-block;">Home</h3>

   <a class="btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" style="font-size:20px;
       font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
       color: #e8d5a0;
       position: absolute;
       top: 600px;
       left: 820px;
       display: inline-block;">Hello</a>
    <section>
       <video class="embed-responsive" height="auto" width="100%" 
            poster="/static/1stframe.jpg" autoplay muted logo loop style="  
            position:fixed;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            min-width: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            z-index:-1;">
            <source src="/static/4k.webm" type="video/webm">
       </video>
    </section>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow">
    <button class="btn">Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @Ashok_Kumar Welcome to SO! Could you please elaborate a bit more in how far this is a solution? I do not see any video here. For more guidance, please also refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer